# Citation language not changing with babel

Tags: biblatex, babel

I have the following in the preamble of my document

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=vancouver]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

However a citation such as:

```
@misc{imgneuroma,
 author = {NHS},
 title = {National Health Service (NHS). Morton's Neuroma 
},
 %year = {2023},
 note = {Accedido: 3 Marzo 2023},
 url = {https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/mortons-neuroma/}
}
```

Appears as:

> NHS. National Health Service (NHS). Morton’s Neuroma. Accedido: 3 Marzo 2023. Available from: https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/mortons-neuroma/

The text 'Available from:' should change to 'Disponible' or something similar, or simply be omitted.

Comment: Note that with `biblatex` you should generally use `urldate` and not the `note` field to give the access date of a URL. `vancouver` hard-codes English there as well, so you may want to restore the standard `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}` or some such field format. This will result different output than shown in your question, but if you insist on this format, things could be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vancouver` style hasn't been written with `babel` in mind and so it redefines the URL field format to include the English text directly, which is why you're not getting the proper Spanish localization. You can fix this by replacing its definition with the the one it should have used in the first place.  Unrelated, but I've put an extra pair of braces around your `{NHS}` author, always good practice for corporate author names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{imgneuroma,
 author = {{NHS}},
 title = {National Health Service (NHS). Morton's Neuroma 
},
 %year = {2023},
 note = {Accedido: 3 Marzo 2023},
 url = {https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/mortons-neuroma/},
 language = {langspanish}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
   style=vancouver,
   ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}: \url{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{imgneuroma}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]